# Extra space between boxed JScrollPanes in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, boxlayout

I'm trying to create a relatively small-scale text based game inside of a `JFrame`. I plan to keep this `JFrame` at a constant size, so I've called `setResizable(false)`.

My goal was to make a text I/O feature that somewhat acted like a console or command prompt, so I have two `JTextArea`s, each inside a `JScollPane`, and then I've added them both to a `Box`, one on top of the other. I wanted these components to keep a constant size, so I called `setPreferredSize()` and `setMaximumSize()` with the appropriate dimensions.

However, when I add two of these Boxes to the `JFrame`, there is a horizontal gap separating them. The gap appears to be attached to the right-hand border of the component. See the attached picture of this behavior:

[image: gaps]).

I'm using a `FlowLayout` in the content pane, with hGap set to 0, and yet there is still a gap between the components I've added, and I cannot figure out why.

To confirm it's not a problem with the `JFrame` itself, or with its layout manager, I've also added two boxes containing buttons to illustrate that they do not have a gap between them.

If at all possible I'd like to remove the gaps, or at least determine what's causing them. At this point I have no idea what else might be causing the issue, and I'd appreciate any advice.

EDIT: Here is a picture of what I'd like this demo class to look like:

[image: no gaps]

I have excerpted the relevant bits of code into this class to demonstrate my problem:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Demo extends JFrame {
    public Demo() {
        super("Demo");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setResizable(false);

        int Y_AXIS = BoxLayout.Y_AXIS;

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);

        Box boxA = new Box(Y_AXIS);
        boxA.add(createComponent("output"));
        boxA.add(createComponent("input"));
        this.add(boxA);

        Box boxB = new Box(Y_AXIS);
        boxB.add(createComponent("output"));
        boxB.add(createComponent("input"));
        this.add(boxB);

        Box boxC = new Box(Y_AXIS);
        boxC.add(new JButton("Button"));
        boxC.add(new JButton("Button"));
        this.add(boxC);

        Box boxD = new Box(Y_AXIS);
        boxD.add(new JButton("Button"));
        boxD.add(new JButton("Button"));
        this.add(boxD);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createComponent(String initial) {
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(3, 10);
        ta.setText(initial);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);

        Dimension pref = new Dimension(100, 100);
        sp.setPreferredSize(pref);
        sp.setMaximumSize(pref);

        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        return sp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo d = new Demo();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) The spaces seem to come from the `Box` rather than the `FlowLayout`.. 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the tip! As you suggested, I revised the post with a picture of what I'd like the GUI to look like. Basically, I just want to remove the gap. Do you have any idea what about the Box might be causing it to appear? I'm baffled--the pairs of JButtons are also in boxes but display no gap.

Comment: I'd probably use four panels for that. 1) A 2x2 `GridLayout` for the text areas. 2) A 2x2 `GridLayout` for the buttons. 3) A `GridBagLayout` for centering the panel containing the buttons. 4) A `BorderLayout` for the text area panel (`LINE_START`), and panel using `GridBagLayout` (`LINE_END`). - Don't mess with the preferred. minimu or maximum size of anything. Add an `EmptyBorder` to the panel with border layout, then pack the frame just before showing it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still very new to the Swing libraries, so I'm not familiar with many of those classes, but I will definitely look into them further in the Java docs. In the meantime, I figured out what was causing the gap to appear--it was the max size call. My code still sets preferred size though, so I'll try to refine it a bit further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the gaps to appear, although I'm not familiar enough with Swing or LayoutManagers to say exactly why.

By removing just the call to `setMaximumSize()` of the interior components, the program works the way I'd like it to. My guess is that one of the layout managers (possibly the `BoxLayout` built into the `Box`?) doesn't behave quite the way I expected when asked to use absolute maximum sizes, instead of relying on the preferred size and letting the layout manager do the work.

Here's the revised code, with the line in question commented out.

```
private JScrollPane createComponent(String initial) {
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(3, 10);
    ta.setText(initial);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);

    Dimension pref = new Dimension(100, 100);
    sp.setPreferredSize(pref);
    //sp.setMaximumSize(pref);

    sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    return sp;
}
```

Although this solution does what I want it to, it is probably not ideal , as Andrew Thompson mentioned in his comment, and I should try to avoid setting any of the preferred/maximum sizes.